# Spring MVC - @ModelAttribute with Long type

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to inject an model attribute using the annotation @ModelAttribute on method argument.

```
@RequestMapping({"/", "/index"})
public String home(Principal principal, Model model, @ModelAttribute("commerceId") Long commerceId) {
    if (commerceId == null) {
        LOGGER.info("Initializing commerce code...");
        String name = principal.getName();
        commerceId = Long.parseLong(name);
        model.addAttribute("commerceId", commerceId);
    }
    return "index";
}
```

But always I get the next exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Long.<init>()
```

I can see that spring is trying to create the Long value using a no-arg constructor, but obviously It will fail because Long type doesn't have no-arg constructor.

Why Spring is unable to create correctly a Long type with @ModelAttribute ?
Can any Wrapper type (Integer, Long, etc...) be injected with @ModelAttribute ?

I'm using Spring 3.1.1

Comment: What value do you expect it to have? Where should that value come from?

Comment: The first time it should be null because it has not be setted.

Comment: I don't think you understand what a model attribute is.

Comment: Did you try with `@RequestParam`?

Comment: Also as you said, there is no empty constructor in `Long`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675987/can-modelattribute-be-primitive

Comment: No, because it isn't a parameter. It comes from logged user (Principal)

Comment: Yeah, I am using a wrapper Long type, not primitive long

Answer (score 5):

eg:

```
@ModelAttribute("peson") Person person
```

First it tries to crate a Person object with no-arg constructor. Then it calls the setter methods to set/populate the values for the respective properties.

In case of

```
@ModelAttribute("commerceId") Long commerceId
```

There is no no-arg constructor, and no setter method to set the value. Primitive Wrapper class provides arg-base constructor, also no setter method. Because once you initialize it, it does not allow you to change the value.

Try with `@RequestParam("commerceId") Long commerceId`

Comment: But it is not a param value thus I cannot use it with that annotation, maybe I must check if the attribute exist with Model class, not using @ModelAttribute

Comment: try `@ModelAttribute("commerceId") String commerceId` then convert it to Long, It will work

Comment: Yes, using a String value works because it give me a empty string when it has not be set.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @ParagFlume, I could change the argument type to String, but that would force me to do a casting to Long in all method using the `@ModelAttribute("commerceId")`.

My solution was create a Wrapper object containing all concerning commerce.

```
public class CommerceData {

    private Long commerceId;

    public Long getCommerceId() {
        return commerceId;
    }

    public void setCommerceId(Long commerceId) {
       this.commerceId = commerceId;
    }
}
```

When user has logged, I create my POJO `CommerceData` and then I set the Long value as attribute. Since I need the model attribute lives in session, I had create manually ant not being injected with `@ModelAttribute` annotation, because Spring MVC claimed the value doesn't exist.

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("data")
public class IndexController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IndexController.class);

    @RequestMapping({"/", "/index"})
    public String home(Principal principal, ModelMap model) {
        if (model.get("data") == null) {
            LOGGER.info("Inicializando código de comercio");
            CommerceData data = new CommerceData();
            String name = principal.getName();
            data.setCommerceId(Long.parseLong(name));
            model.addAttribute("data", data);
        }
        return "index";
    }
}
```

But I believe that Spring MVC should support inject Wrappers values (Long, Integer, Double) using @ModelAttribute and not only POJO classes. Maybe I wrong but I could not do work with `@ModelAttribute("commerceId") Long commerceId`.

Answer (score -2):

primitives work better with @modelattribute in spring . 
i also faced issue with Long type but when used long then issue is resolved.